# React - Native IOS build failed

Tags: xcode, react-native

warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'workreap' from project 'workreap')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'workreap' from project 'workreap')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Config codegen' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'react-native-config' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/newuser/Desktop/react\ Naative\ \ functionnal\ based/New\ code/workreap-react-main-files/will\ work/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/newuser/Desktop/react\ Naative\ \ functionnal\ based/New\ code/workreap-react-main-files/will\ work/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

"I am trying to run ios version of my code and i keep getting this error"
I have run
npm install
cd ios
pod install
Cd ..
react-native run-IOS

I have Deleted Pod dir and .xcworkspace
deleted node_modules and repeated the process I still get same errors

Comment: I have started being the same issue on Azure pipeline on last week, I'm using the vm-pool macOS-12 to build the IOS React Native project, so on the last week the Apple release the new Xcode 14.0.1 on 26 Sep 2022, and after that some apps are having the same issue as us, therefore I needed to force the Xcode version on build pipeline to Xcode 13.4.1 or Xcode 14.0 and the build works as before.
List of xcode release: https://xcodereleases.com/